# android: trouble with Arabic font

Tags: android, arabic

It shows correctly on xperia x8(gingerxperia). but the letters and symbols are not shown correctly in Motorola Photon. Images attached. Unicodes used are: ("\u062D"+"\u064D"), ("\u062E"+"\u064D"), ("\u0639"+"\u064D"), ("\u063A"+"\u064D").

Photon:

[image: Motorola Photon]

Xperia(correct):

[image: Xperia x8]

Is there a way to solve this? Thanks for Help in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you need to thoroughly check out if the Motorola Photon is indeed rendering bidi text correctly. Am sure there would be something in the market to confirm this for you that can tell if bidi is rendering properly.

It could be down to the ROM used on the Motorola Photon. Perhaps an update is available to fix it?

bidi == Bi-Directional for arabic/hebrew text.

A quick google-fu on XDA yielded this [linky](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=701281) that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

use custom fonts that has all Arabic glyphs.

```
Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/myfonts.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(font1);
```

try these fonts
http://www.4shared.com/file/0ZWijAyt/Wikoles_Store_-_Arabic_Android.html

Comment: I'm already using some fonts. however, thanks for more fonts :)